# Why does php function "json_encode" applied for a not-associative array with a missing first element consider second key as string?

Tags: php

Lets begin with two small tests:

---

```
$original = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b'];
var_dump((json_decode(json_encode($original))));
```

returns

```
array(2) { // array
    [0]=> // integer like original
        string(1) "a"
    [1]=> // integer like original
        string(1) "b"
}
```

So we can see here, that `assoc` parameter (second parameter in `json_decode` function) is not set (default is `false`), and pair `json_decode-json_encode` recovers original as it should.

---

```
$original = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'];
var_dump((json_decode(json_encode($original))));
```

returns

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { // object
    ["1"]=> // string, instead of integer
        string(1) "a"
    ["2"]=> // string, instead of integer
        string(1) "b"
}
```

Here again, `assoc` is `false`, but pair `json_decode-json_encode` can't recover original unless we explicitly set `assoc` into `true`.

---

**Question:** I am working on a custom serialization process (different from PHP `serialize` and `unserialize` functions). I decided to use `json_decode-json_encode` pair and I found that I can't rely on default settings, like `assoc=false`. Are you aware of any other pitfalls with `json_` family functions that may lead me to a problem when I won't be able to recover original data and structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON encoding for an array looks like:

```
[ element, element, element, ... ]
```

As you can see, there are no explicit indexes, so this encoding can only be used when the array contains consecutive numeric indexes starting from 0.

Any other array is encoded as an object, and object keys are always strings in JSON. When you decode an object with `json_decode()` it returns a PHP object if `assoc` is `false`, an associative array if it's `true`.

When you go through the JSON encoding process for an object, there's no way to tell whether the original array had numeric or string indexes. They'll always become strings in JSON.

Furthermore, when you use `assoc = false`, and the result is an object, the properties necessarily have to be strings, because PHP objects can't have numeric property names.

When you use `assoc = false` you recover the original because PHP itself doesn't distinguish between numbers and numeric strings as indexes in an array. If you do:

```
var_dump( array('1' => 'a', 2 => 'b'));
```

the result is:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

As you can see, PHP automatically turned the string `'1'` into the number `1` when creating the array.

JSON was never intended to be used to encode objects in any language without information loss. It's designed as a simple format that facilitates communication between applications that may be written in different languages. So it abstracts away many of the details, and just supports basic arrays and objects. Other formats like XML and `serialize` allow more precision.

Comment: Well, they could do `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` on the encode.

Comment: That only affects the values, not the keys.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the problem we had 3 options (an array with 3 elements) that was stored as JSON encoded string. Later we decided to get rid of first option, so we decoded the string -> deleted [0] element -> encoded the string and then faced this problem when array has turned into object.