# array_unique inconsistent for simple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Why is it that

```
echo json_encode(array_unique([1,2,3,4,4]));
```

Outputs

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

And

```
echo json_encode(array_unique([1,2,3,3,4]));
```

Outputs

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"4":4}
```

This has lead to some very odd bugs for me, and I simply cannot understand what's going on here. I just want to remove the duplicates from the array and have it returned as an array.

Comment: `array_unique()` does not reindex your array, so when you encode it in json it will include the keys in the output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362192/why-php-function-json-encode-applied-for-a-not-associative-array-with-a-missin

Comment: @Rizier123 - but why not in the first case? Both arrays supplied as arguments have duplicate integers in them.

Comment: @nickdnk Read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11722121/3933332 there are many similar questions.

Comment: @nickdnk what you need is this: `json_encode(array_values(array_unique([1,2,3,3,4])));`

Comment: Aha. Okay. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_unique([1,2,3,4,4])` returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}
```

> Note that the keys are sequential

While `array_unique([1,2,3,3,4]))` returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(4)
}
```

> Note the **jump** between the key `2` and the key `4`.

Because of that - `json_encode` will omit the `keys` in the first array (and keep it as `array` object), while in the second array - the `json_encode` will look at your `array` as `object` and will keep the keys.

You can use `array_values` (to get the values and ignore the `keys`).